# converting array in two dimension

Tags: php, mysql

i have this result as a mysql_fetch_row function which return rows from database...

```
Array
(
    [firstname] => abc
    [lastname] => xyz
    [password] => abc
    [gender] => female
    [city] => malborne
    [email] => abc@gmail.com
    [address] => abc
)
```

i want this array as

```
Array
(
  [0] array(


        [firstname] => abc
        [lastname] => xyz
        [password] => abc
        [gender] => female
        [city] => malborne
        [email] => abc@gmail.com
        [address] => abc

)
)
```

Comment: Please post your existing MySQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = array($data);
print_r($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => abc
            [lastname] => xyz
            [password] => abc
            [gender] => female
            [city] => malborne
            [email] => abc@gmail.com
            [address] => abc
        )

)
```

[Ta-dah!](http://codepad.org/1yYSuhz1)

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy you can create the structure you want by inserting it inside another array

```
$original = array(.....);
$final = array($original);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_row(...)) {
  $myArray[] = $row;
}
// $myArray is your final array
```